# SQL Server 2005 Date Time stamp Query

Tags: sql-server, datetime

One of my columns type is DateTime (Date Registered). I cannot create a query that filters all the data for eg. All registrations who registered on the 22/10/2008 between 18:00 and 20:00.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateRegistered BETWEEN '10/22/2008 18:00:00' AND '10/22/2008 20:00:00'
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using datediff?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx