# Specific Time Range Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I'm trying to query a specific range of time:

- i.e. 3/1/2009 - 3/31/2009
- between 6AM-10PM each day
- Tues/Wed/Thurs only

I've seen that you can get data for a particular range, but only for start to end and this is quite a bit more specific.  I didn't see any SQL Server commands that would directly help me on this, so does anybody else have any thoughts on how you would form this?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357244/sql-server-2005-date-time-stamp-query), but I don't think it's nearly specific enough for this range.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have date and time in the same column, or separate?

Comment: Same Column - it is just a DateTime field

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm assuming you want all three of those as part of the selection criteria.  You'll need a few statements in your where but they will be similar to the link your question contained.

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE [dateColumn] > '3/1/2009' AND [dateColumn] <= DATEADD(day,1,'3/31/2009') 
        --make it inclusive for a datetime type
    AND DATEPART(hh,[dateColumn]) >= 6 AND DATEPART(hh,[dateColumn]) <= 22 
        -- gets the hour of the day from the datetime
    AND DATEPART(dw,[dateColumn]) >= 3 AND DATEPART(dw,[dateColumn]) <= 5 
        -- gets the day of the week from the datetime
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Syntax for dateadd is `DATEADD(datepart,number,date)`
Sample should be:
`...<= DATEADD(day, 1, '3/31/2009')`

Source: [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: Yeah but how would you do this if the time was not precise to exact hour for example if you want in time range from 6:15 AM to 10:35 AM?

Answer (score 6):

you can try this (I don't have sql server here today so I can't verify syntax, sorry)

```
select attributeName
  from tableName
 where CONVERT(varchar,attributeName,101) BETWEEN '03/01/2009' AND '03/31/2009'
   and CONVERT(varchar, attributeName,108) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '22:00:00'
   and DATEPART(day,attributeName) BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Comment: Thanks :) It's very similar to what Giggy suggested.  I tried this originally after his suggestion, but decided to go with strict equality signs as they removed the ambiguity of what part of 'between' is inclusive :)

Answer (score 2):

I (using PostgrSQL on PGadmin4) queried for results that are after or on 21st Nov 2017 at noon, like this (considering the display format of hours on my database):

```
select * from Table1 where FIELD >='2017-11-21 12:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where 
(dtColumn between #3/1/2009# and #3/31/2009#) and 
(hour(dtColumn) between 6 and 22) and 
(weekday(dtColumn, 1) between 2 and 4)
```

Comment: This is valid SQL Server 2005 syntax?  It's not according to my SQLServer

Comment: Does this even work in 2008?  Seems like useful date functions took until 2012 to become available.

Comment: I really do not think that is a real T-sql method.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get results for specific time period, use the query below:

```
Select * from [your_table_name] 
where date between '2021-10-05' AND '2021-12-10'
```