# sql query where date between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specific Time Range Query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885188/specific-time-range-query-in-sql-server)

For example I have 3 rows:

```
Id      Date
1       '2011-01-02 09:14:23.0000000' 
2       '2011-02-15 10:15:47.0000000' 
3       '2011-03-18 21:12:33.0000000'
```

And I whant to take only rows, where TIME between 09:00 and 11:00 and any date.

I need this in result set:

```
 Id      Date
    1       '2011-01-02 09:14:23.0000000' 
    2       '2011-02-15 10:15:47.0000000'
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885188/specific-time-range-query-in-sql-server

Comment: thanks, seems to be true, I try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach

```
SELECT id, date 
FROM myTable 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Date,108) between '09:00:00' and '11:00:00'
```

Comment: DATEPART(hh, Date) BETWEEN 9 and 11 - select date with 11:45 time - it is wrong