# specific range of time in Sql 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

If found this question which really exactly like my need the only problem its my range of time is 21:00 to 5:00 am!

[Specific Time Range Query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885188/specific-time-range-query-in-sql-server)

I need a query for the whole between 21:00 to 05:00

but i made a query the problem is my query return 21:00 to 23:59 for the month

```
Select BeginServiceTime,FinishServiceTime From table where
(BeginServiceTime between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-31') and          
  DATEPART(hh,BeginServiceTime) >= 21
```

And i need to make another one for the 00:01 to 05:00 like :

```
Select BeginServiceTime,FinishServiceTime From table where
(BeginServiceTime between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-31') and          
  DATEPART(hh,BeginServiceTime) =< 5
```

the question : how can i make both in 1 query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values between 21:00 and 05:00 are logically the opposite of the values between 05:00 and 21:00 so you could just invert the condition to filter out times between 05:00 and 21:00:

```
where (BeginServiceTime between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-31') 
  and not (DATEPART(hh,BeginServiceTime) < 21 and DATEPART(hh,BeginServiceTime) > 5)
```

If you want more control over the times you filter by you could cast the datetime to a time value and use this:

```
and not (
  cast(BeginServiceTime as time) > '05:00:00' and cast(BeginServiceTime as time) < '21:00:00'
)
```

Comment: lol man i'm slapping me in the face right now ,i need to try this!!!Never think of invert the condition!