# Spark DataFrame query between 2 specific Time Range

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with a column having Date in the format dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm.

How to do TimeRange query like -

> Find all the rows between 2 dates and within specific time range of
>   4PM to 1AM.

This is possible in sql by using DatePart [Specific Time Range Query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885188/specific-time-range-query-in-sql-server)

How to do the same in Spark Dataframe.

For example,

> I want to find all the rows between 23-MAR-2016 till 25-MAR-2016 ,
>   within time range from **13:00:00 till 18:00:00** only.

So I must get only one row as result.

```
var input = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (13L, "Abhi c", "22-MAR-2016 09:10:12"),
        (11L, "VF", "23-MAR-2016 16:24:25"),
        (12L, "Alice Jones", "24-MAR-2016 19:20:25")
        )).toDF("id", "name", "time")

input.filter("time between '23-MAR-2016' and '25-MAR-2016'").show()

+---+-----------+--------------------+
| id|       name|                time|
+---+-----------+--------------------+
| 11|         VF|23-MAR-2016 16:24:25|
| 12|Alice Jones|24-MAR-2016 19:20:25|
+---+-----------+--------------------+
```

My Above query only filtered the date and even I can give time but how to get rows within a time range of each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp

var input = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (13L, "Abhi c", "22-MAR-2016 09:10:12"),
    (11L, "VF", "23-MAR-2016 16:24:25"),
    (12L, "Alice Jones", "24-MAR-2016 19:20:25")
    )).toDF("id", "name", "time")

val h = hour(unix_timestamp($"time", "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"))

input.withColumn("hour", h).filter("time BETWEEN '23-MAR-2016' AND '25-MAR-2016' AND hour BETWEEN 13 AND 18").show()

+---+----+--------------------+----+
| id|name|                time|hour|
+---+----+--------------------+----+
| 11|  VF|23-MAR-2016 16:24:25|  16|
+---+----+--------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to retrieve the hour of a timestamp. Here is how to select data that lies between 10am and 1pm in [PySpark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hour):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import hour

data.select("ts").where((hour("ts") > 10) & (hour("ts") < 13))
```

You can further filter with, e.g., `pyspark.sql.functions.month`, `pyspark.sql.functions.year`, or `pyspark.sql.functions.dayofmonth`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in case **if you don't want to add any new intermediate columns** to your dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

var input = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((13L, "Abhi c", "22-MAR-2016 09:10:12"), (11L, "VF", "23-MAR-2016 16:24:25"), (12L, "Alice Jones", "24-MAR-2016 19:20:25"))).toDF("id", "name", "time")

val ts = unix_timestamp($"time", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp")

input.filter("time between '23-MAR-2016' and '25-MAR-2016'").filter(hour(ts) >= 13 && hour(ts) <= 18).show
```

Output:

```
+---+----+--------------------+
| id|name|                time|
+---+----+--------------------+
| 11|  VF|23-MAR-2016 16:24:25|
+---+----+--------------------+
```